# Add-in for input() with validation

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, validation, casting

What do you think about this code? Do you have some advices and remarks for me about them? I have started learning python recently.

```
types = {
    "str": str,
    "int": int,
    "float": float,
    "complex": complex
}


def my_input(kind, msg, msg_wrong, detail):
    """ Add-in for input(). Performs validation of the data entered.
    :param kind: data type. The keys of the dictionary types. 
                 If an error occurs, a str is expected.
    :param msg: a welcome message, such as "Enter a number -> "
    :param msg_wrong: own message in case of error
    :param detail: detailed error description (True or False)
    :return: entered value with type kind
    """
    method = types.get(kind, str)
    while True:
        try:
            value = method(input(msg))
            break
        except ValueError as e:
            print(msg_wrong, detail * str(e))
    return value


msg = "-> "
msg_wrong = "Error"

print(my_input("int", msg, msg_wrong, False))
print(my_input("hello", msg, msg_wrong, True))  # wrong type, will str
print(my_input("complex", msg, msg_wrong, True))

"""
-> hi
Error 
-> 15
15
-> some text
some text
-> some text 2
Error complex() arg is a malformed string
-> 4-j
(4-1j)
"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your function looks usable, useful and follows PEP8, well done.
2. Coupling `types` and `kind` together seems like a poor descision. Since functions are firstclass in Python you can just pass the function.

   This would change your functions to something like:

   > ```
   > my_input(int, msg, msg_wrong, False)
   > ```

   This would have the drawback that if you don't pass a valid function, then it will blow-up. But has the added benifit of allowing more types with less code.

   > ```
   > import datetime
   > my_input(datetime.fromisoformat, msg, msg_wrong, False)
   > ```

   You can also fix the drawback by changing `kind` to an argument with a default value.

   > ```
   > def my_input(msg, msg_wrong, detail, kind=str)
   > my_input(msg, msg_wrong, True)
   > ```
3. It's not immediatly clear why you would want to log only certain errors with the `detail` argument.

   If I were to show or silence errors I would use the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).
   I'll leave configuring the logger to you, but usage would be:

   ```
   import logging

   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

   ...

   def my_input(kind, msg, msg_wrong):
       method = types.get(kind, str)
       while True:
           try:
               value = method(input(msg))
               break
           except ValueError as e:
               logger.debug(e)
               print(msg_wrong)
       return value

   ...

   print(my_input("int", msg, msg_wrong))
   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   print(my_input("hello", msg, msg_wrong))
   print(my_input("complex", msg, msg_wrong))
   ```

   It's not apparent to me why you'd like to log some but not other errors. If being able to change the level of different calls to `my_input` is of the upmost importance then it'd make more sense to me for you to pass the logging level.

   > ```
   > def my_input(kind, msg, msg_wrong, level=logging.DEBUG):
   >     ...
   >             logger.log(level, e)
   > ```
4. I'm not used to seeing assignment, break and then a return out of a while true loop. When I do this I only use return.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def my_input(msg, msg_wrong, cast=str):
    while True:
        try:
            return cast(input(msg))
        except ValueError as e:
            logger.debug(e)
            print(msg_wrong)


msg = "-> "
msg_wrong = "Error"

print(my_input(msg, msg_wrong, int))
print(my_input(msg, msg_wrong))
print(my_input(msg, msg_wrong, complex))
```

Comment: What do you mean by word "cast"? I don't understand it with translation to my language. 

If I do how your fourth example, IDE PyCharm gives me notice "Expected type Type[str] got Type[int] instead". I add in docstring ":type cast: str, int, float, complex" (for Python 3) and notice disappears. Is it a right decision?

Comment: Hmm.. If I write ":type cast: str, " that notice disappears too.

Comment: @Owl [Here's a Wikipedia page for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion), I'm unsure if it has been translated into your language however. In short `a = 1; b = str(a)` "casts" (converts) `a` from int to string and assigns it to `b`. I think using `cast: Type = str` would also fix the problem.